# value of `google` prop in Map component

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

Trying to use `google-maps-react` library.
i imported the following:`import {Map,Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'`

one thing is unclear here and i could not find answer on tutorials.

```
<Map google={this.props.google} />
```

what's the value of `google` prop on the `Map` component? will it be the `apikey`?

Comment: You can look up what the props using the react devtools extension or by simply console logging it

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation `google` is a reference to the `window.google` object.

So it's instance of `google` api with your configuration like `apiKey` as you said.

See all configuration from [HERE](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/lib/GoogleApi.js#L4)

You can see the whole section [HERE](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react#subcomponents)